# Signalr JS serverless close session

Tags: javascript, signalr

Coming from socket.io I had on the server side the following code:

```
  socket.on("disconnect", async () => {})
```

When the user closes the Tap or refreshes the page.

I need to know if I can implement the same functionality, (ofc different implementation) on the server side (in the attached highlighted)
or if it is doable
do I need to create an HttpTrigger that calls the process needed in the disconnect functionality?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After digging through the issue I had finally found a solution:

```
  <script>
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  const data = {
    userId: localStorage.getItem("outside"),
  }
  console.log("looog", data);
  // alert("IUIUIU")
  fetch("API_URL_ENDS_THE_SESSION", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })

  e = e || window.event;

  // // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Sure?';
  }

  // // For Safari
  return 'Sure?';
}
```